# How to override the jQuery.ajax success function after it has been initialized?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

A button click triggers an ajax request. When the user clicks the button a second time while the first request is still loading, i want to override the first request's success function with another one.

Basically I want to do this:

```
var ajaxRequest = null;

jQuery('#mybutton').click(function () {
    if (ajaxRequest) {
        ajaxRequest.success = function () {
        };
    }

    ajaxRequest = jQuery.ajax({
        url: '...',
        success: function () {
            console.debug('do something');
        }
    });
});
```

But the initial success handler is been called.
How to achieve an override?

Comment: What is the use case where you want to override? With the code snippet you provided the second line seems redundant.

Comment: A button click triggers an ajax request. When the user clicks the button a second time while the first request is still loading, i want to override the first request's success function with another one.

Comment: What are success function doing? Maybe you can use some dynamic DOM manipulation instead?

Comment: _How to achieve an override?_...Well i guess it should not be required. But are you going to make use of response data somewhere else too?

Comment: Let me describe my use case - if I click the button, a jQuery.ajax request gets fired. If you click a second, third, 4th, 5th, .. time, the current request (if present) should get an empty success handler ( function() {} ), so only the last request should have the right success handler. I will update my code above to explain what I mean.

Comment: @Simon , you should add your second comment to question so that its easy to understand and follow

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following hack, I have tested it with asynch setTimeout (instead of asynch jQuery.ajax) and it works -

```
var mySuccessHander = function() {
    console.debug('Initial function');
}

var test = jQuery.ajax({
    url: '...',
    success: function() {
        mySuccessHander();
    }
});
```

And when the button is clicked for the second time, execute following -

```
mySuccessHander = function() {
    console.debug('Overridden function');
}
```

Comment: Let me describe my use case - if I click the button, a jQuery.ajax request gets fired. If you click a second, third, 4th, 5th, .. time, the current request (if present) should get an empty success handler ( function() {} ), so only the last request should have the right success handler. I will update my code above to explain what I mean.

Comment: But how do you predict which click is the last one? Users can click as many times as they want and they might not click after clicking for certain times.

Comment: When I reset the last ajaxRequest's success handler with each click, the last request automatically has the only right success handler, that's what I want to do.

Comment: Yes, so everytime the user clicks on the button you can change the `mySuccessHandler` with last time what you assigned.

Comment: Unfortunately not, because all requests will then use the new handler. I only want to update the ones before the current. See my code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the ajax arguments to a variable first so you can modify it later on.

```
var clicks = 0,
    ajaxArgs = {
        url: '...',
        success: function () {
            console.debug('do something');
        }
    };


$('#myButton').click(function() {
    ++clicks; 
    if (clicks > 1) {
        // set the success function if clicked more than once
        ajaxArgs.success = function () {
            console.debug('Success function ' + clicks);
        }
    }

    $.ajax(ajaxArgs);
});
```

If you want to modify the success function only when ajax is still loading you can do this:

```
var loading = false,
    ajaxArgs = {
        url: '...',
        success: function () {
            console.debug('do something');
        }, complete: function () {
            loading = false;
        }
    };

$('#myButton').click(function() {
    if (loading) {
        // set the success function if ajax is still loading
        ajaxArgs.success = function () {
            console.debug('Another Success function ');
        }
    } else {
        loading = true;
        $.ajax(ajaxArgs);
    }
});
```

Comment: See the answer above - I want to change the success handler of the requests before this one and still let the last request have the actual success function.

Answer (score 1):

Nice question , this will work..

```
var isRequestDone = true;

jQuery('#mybutton').click(function () {
    var requestParams = {
        url: '....',
        beforeSend: function () {
            isRequestDone = false;
        },
        success: function () {
            isRequestDone = true;
            console.debug('do something');
        },
        error: function () {
            isRequestDone = true;
        }
    }
    if (!isRequestDone) {
        requestParams.success = function () {
            console.log('please wait for a while!'); 
        };
    }

    jQuery.ajax(requestParams);
});
```

`beforeSend` will fire just before the request will go to server , so when request in on the server `isRequestDone` will be false and hence will change success handler . on success callback from the first request it will again back to original.

Comment: Yep, that's a good idea. Just to feed my curiosity, if I have the jQuery.ajax object of a currently-in-progress request, I cannot change it's success handler nor any other stuff of it (basically that's what my question is about)?

Comment: see , almost all javascript framework provides async behaviour , as that's what in nature of javascript (that callback stuff) , if you want to achieve with your code , you should have request blocking behaviour which you can accomplish like http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Snippets%3a_Synchronous_AJAX (examples also there.) and for sure you'll find similar for JQuery too... good luck..

Comment: Well, my use case was not to prevent the user from clicking the button again, but the requests before should have an other ajax handler instead. Synchronous AJAX would freeze the browser until the request is completed, so you cannot click the button again in that time. (it can btw be accomplished by adding async: false to the jQuery.ajax option object), and your example sets the last request's success function - but I want to change the success handler of the requests before this one and still let the last request have the actual success function.